# How to return an object from a sample data in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am playing with sample data. I don't have any data in database at this moment.

```
{ 
   "Name": "john",
   "ProductIds: [1, 2, 3],
   "Products": [
    { 
      "description": [
         { 
           "a": "abc"
         },
         { 
           "b": "def"
         }
       ] 
     }
   ]
}
```

E.g when we do `Customer.all` we get the result something like below:

```
 [#<Customer:0x00007fd75542f250
  id: "123",
  customer_name: "sam",
  city: "Houston",
  state: "Texas"]
```

I have this data in model and I am trying to write a method to return this sample data as an object.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Structs.

```
class Customer
  def self.all(collection)
    customer = Struct.new(:name, :address)
    collection.map {|e| customer.new(e[:name], e[:address])}
  end
end

collection = [
  {name: "pepe", address: "abc"},
  {name: "ciro"}
]

Customer.all(collection) #=> [
 #<struct name="pepe", address="abc">,
 #<struct name="ciro", address=nil>
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create a mock class in order to return your sample data. Something like that:

```
class CustomerRepositroyMock
   DATA = [
     { .... json data here }
   ]

   def self.all
      DATA.map{ |payload| Product.new(.... init attributes here) }
   end
end
```

The above will return an array of new Product instances. Hope that helps.

Comment: Tried to do this  **def self.all
    MOCK_DATA.map do |t|
      Mock.new(
        name: t[:name]
      )
    end
  end** but getting error no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer

Comment: Your `MOCK_DATA` contains a JSON instead of a hash, you need to parse it (or just put a ruby hash in MOCK_DATA). To parse: `require 'json'; JSON.parse(string)`